# How to create new pandas row at every "\n" instance?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo\nbar', 'tre\ndex', 'hello\nworld'],
                   'B': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']})
```

There are 3 rows made of strings (including `\n` but I'd like to separate the string into two whenever `\n` appears and match the values from the `B` column with the newly created row, giving me the following DataFrame:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'tre' 'dex', 'hello', 'world],
                       'B': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def' ,'ghi', 'ghi']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) `A` and then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) it:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split('\n')
df = df.explode('A').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       A    B
0    foo  abc
1    bar  abc
2    tre  def
3    dex  def
4  hello  ghi
5  world  ghi
```

Or, more tersely:

```
df = df.assign(A=df['A'].str.split('\n')).explode("A")
```

Comment: `df['A'].str.split('\n')` is safer in case you also have spaces

Comment: @mozway true, I've edited